# read prompt doesn't print correctly when run within Makefile

Tags: bash, makefile

I'm trying to prompt user input but I'm having trouble to get `read -p` prompt getting printed as expected when run from within a Makefile or a subshell started by a Makefile. Here are my attempts on achieving this without success:

```
test1:
    @echo '>> before input <<'; \
        read -p 'type something:' FOO; \
        echo '>> after input <<'; \
        echo $$FOO
```

The output looks like this assuming I input `asdf`. My input gets printed as I type, but the prompt `type something:` gets printed after everything else:

```
$ make
>> before input <<
asdf
>> after input <<
asdf
type something
```

Another way I've tried is using Bash's readline interface `read -e`:

```
test2:
    @echo '>> before input <<'; \
        read -e -p 'type something:' FOO; \
        echo '>> after input <<'; \
        echo $$FOO
```

In this case the output looks good, however, neither the prompt `type something:` nor the actual input as I type get printed until after I have pressed `ENTER`, which is quite inconvenient when asking for input.

I also tried printing the prompt before with `echo`:

```
test3:
    @echo '>> before input <<'; \
        echo 'input something:';\
        read FOO; \
        echo '>> after input <<'; \
        echo $$FOO;\
```

And my output looks almost good, but the input is printed on a newline:

```
$ make
>> before input <<
input something:
asdf
>> after input <<
asdf
```

One final tweak using `printf` to avoid the newline:

```
test4:
    @echo '>> before input <<'; \
        printf 'input something: ';\
        read FOO; \
        printf '\n'; \
        echo '>> after input <<'; \
        echo $$FOO;\
```

And it seems `read` eats away the prompt if it doesn't end with `\n`:

```
$ make
>> before input <<
asdf
input something:
>> after input <<
asdf
```

And, of course, exactly the same happens if I simply call a script:

```
test5:
    ./script.sh
```

In case it helps spotting the problem: OS X 10.10.3 / make 3.81 / bash 3.2.57(1).

Disclaimer: I know it's not a good idea to have user input dependant Makefiles, but I need this for a very particular case.

Comment: First of all, you want this behavior per Makefile target, I understand, not globally per Makefile.

Comment: I tried running test1 on my mac, which has identical versions of the used applications. The output I get is:
`bash-3.2$ make test1
>> before input <<
type something:TESTING
>> after input <<
TESTING`
Which leads me to believe that we need more information to resolve the issue. Did you make any changes to how bash or make behaves?

Comment: I think you are onto something here, @Ashlaban. Commenting out my `.zshrc` makes read behave as expected in all cases. I'll investigate what I have in there that is causing this weird issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since apparently nobody could reproduce my issue, I figured I had to have something going on on my environment causing it. I finally found the cause was lurking somewhere on my pile of tweaks within `.zshrc`.

The offending line turns out to be an aliased `make` for adding colorization with `grc` that somehow modifies the behavior of `read` as a side effect.

```
alias make='grc make'
```

Removing it solves all the issues, but, in the end, my solution is to keep the alias for colorization in normal circumstances and simply invoke `command make` when user input is required.

Comment: The way to bypass alias is `command make` or `\make`. No offense, but `/usr/bin/env make` is just ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

For `test 3` you can use `echo -n` to print your message on the same line without the trailing `\n`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. It prints: `-n input something:`

Answer (score 0):

In your examples, you are running basically a single shell command. It is possible to run a series of commands and I think that's what you want here. For example try this. Put in your Makefile:

```
test1:
    @echo '>> before input <<'
    read -p 'type something: ' FOO; \
    echo '>> after input <<'; \
    echo $$FOO
```

Note that lack of a semicolon and backslash on the first @echo.